# How to get tag name of root element in an XML document w/ XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm interested in assigning the tag name of the root element in an xml document to an xslt variable.  For instance, if the document looked like (minus the DTD):

```
<foo xmlns="http://.....">
    <bar>1</bar>
</foo>
```

and I wanted to assign the string 'foo' to an xslt variable.  Is there a way to reference that?

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you want to retrieve the name of the outermost XML element. This can be done like in the following XSL sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="outermostElementName" select="name(/*)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$outermostElementName"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note that there is a slight difference in XPath terminology:

> The top of the tree is a root node
>   (1.0 terminology) or document node
>   (2.0). This is what "/" refers to.
>   It's not an element: it's the parent
>   of the outermost element (and any
>   comments and processing instructions
>   that precede or follow the outermost
>   element). The root node has no name.

See http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/root.html#d9799e301

Answer (score 22):

Use the XPath [**`name()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-name) function.

One XPath expression to obtain the name of the top (not root!) element is:

**`name(/*)`**

The name() function returns the fully-qualified name of the node, so for an element `<bar:foo/>` the string "bar:foo" will be returned.

In case only the local part of the name is wanted (no prefix and ":"), then the XPath [**`local-name()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-local-name) function should be used.

Comment: Alternatively `/*/name()`

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz, `/*/name()` will raise an error if one uses an XPath 1 processor, while name(/*) works nicely both with XPath 1.0 processors and with ones that implement versions higher than 1.0. So, 100% of the readers of this answer will benefit from it, while probably 80% will be frustrated by the failure to use `/*/name()`

Comment: Good point, but sometimes you're not after compatibility. I was using a processor that forces me to specify a base XPath to loop (eg. /*), and then map the remaining XPath to fields. This way, my proposed solution was handy. But it is good to know it isn't compatible with older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  The function name() given the parameter * will return foo.

Answer (score 0):

you want **[local-name()](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_local-name.html)**

Comment: @annakata: name() and local-name() are differnt. The OP clearly wants name(). Nowhere does he say that he wants the name stripped off any namespace prefix.

Comment: To be fair I mean "this will do what you want" not "only this..." and nowhere in the OP does it say he wants the namespace either. I don't know about you but in my experience local-name is what I'm interested in 90%+ of the time. namespaces are one of the reasons people hate XSLT