# Select name of root element with XPath in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, xpath, document-root

I've got a bunch of XML messages in a PostgreSQL 9.1.3 table, with a column `content` of type XML).  They're not all the same "type", so I'm trying to extract the root type using a query like this:

```
SELECT xpath('name(/*)', content) FROM message;
```

as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369196/63991) to a similar SO question.

A sample message is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WML version="6" xmlns="http://example.com/schemas/WML">...</WML>
```

For which case I'd hope to get the result '{WML}'.  Unfortunately it just returns an empty array.  Adding the namespaces parameter to `xpath`, or removing the namespace from the message, does not help.

A discussion on the PostgreSQL mailing lists seems to [explain it as a bug](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2008-07/msg00058.php) in XPath handling in PostgreSQL.  However that was in 2008, and a look at the PostgreSQL source shows that piece of code [was changed](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=c9cab106f6f8d0807f3f56db39826dc0030236b3;hp=1079564979dc2fecfadaddd6808ea2343a782ba6) in 2009.  I'm not a PostgreSQL developer so I'm not confident that the bug is or is not a factor in my case.

But I'm wondering if there's a workaround, such as an alternative XPath expression that might work?  I'd prefer not to have to resort to regular expressions to parse XML, though if you can suggest a short, punchy,  robust RE then it would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a workaround for older versions, but this is fixed in PostgreSQL 9.2, so that's great.

(The likeliest workaround would likely to have been to write a function to parse the XML manually, but I'm glad I don't have to resort to that now!)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, this has not yet been solved as of June 2011.
I found [this thread on `pgsql-hackers`](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2011-05/msg01521.php) that describes your problem exactly.