# get the namespace prefix and namespace binding of an XML element

Tags: xml, xpath

For the following XML instance:

```
<foo:a xmlns:foo="http://foo"> <b> whatever </b>   </foo:a>
```

One can use the `local-name(/*)` and `name(/*)` XPath expressions to get `a` and `foo:a` respectively (as shown in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368668/how-to-get-tag-name-of-root-element-in-an-xml-document-w-xslt)).

Are there any XPath expressions to:

- get me the namespace binding of the root -or any other- element (`http://foo`)
- directly get me the namespace prefix of the root -or any other- element (`foo`)

Comment: Does your XML really have the backslashes in it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders re the backlashes, no my bad I copy-pasted the XML out of a String literal in code, have now fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use namespace-uri:

```
namespace-uri(/*)
```

Comment: And as for the other question, the only way to get the prefix is to use name() and extract the part before the colon.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this works to get the prefix (xpath 2.0):

```
prefix-from-QName(node-name())
```